# Changing countries makes iTunes unable to locate music

Tags: itunes, music

I have switched from country A to country B, however **all** of my music in my library is now unable to be located and comes up with those exclamation marks.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use iTunes Match (and haven’t downloaded the music to your library). If the problem is caused not downloading the music, switch back to your original country and download all the music before switching to your preferred country.

**Side Notes**: Everything you purchase on iTunes is tied to your Apple ID according to its active country. If you purchase music on Unites States iTunes Store, you won’t be able to download them when you switch to Japan iTunes Store.

You can certainly switch between country to download your past purchases, but I suggest to maintain one Apple ID to avoid this complicated process.

Comment: that does not sound right for already downloaded music

Comment: I assume he uses iTunes Match to encounter this type of problem.

Comment: so just disable the match ?

Comment: I don’t think he has downloaded all the music. No detail about it is given in the question.

Comment: lets fine tune your answer anyway :) for downloaded disable the match, for not downloaded change the country back to the origin.

Comment: @Buscar웃 yup, edited, that should do it.

Comment: and you have been rewarded :)